# Primary and secondary zone's links in drupal 7

Tags: routes, navigation

This is my website in drupal 7. The page at `http://150.254.36.80/wige/kandydaci/aktualnosci` shows the following header.

[image: http://150.254.36.80/wige/kandydaci/aktualnosci]

I would like that "kandydaci" in this white menu will be active (black lighted) in every page in this zone, for example on `http://150.254.36.80/wige/kandydaci/o-wydziale`.

[image: http://150.254.36.80/wige/kandydaci/o-wydziale]

We are in the "kandydaci" zone, but the white menu doesn't show it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Menu Position](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position) module to accomplish this.

After installing:

1. Visit /admin/structure/menu-position
2. Click "Add menu position rule"
3. Select the parent menu item "kandydaci"
4. Add a page restriction for "kandydaci/*"

This should keep the "kandydaci" menu link active on the correct pages.